# How to put unordered (gif image) list in middle?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list within a body and the body tag is aligned to the center, the text for the ul list goes to the middle but the gif image stays to the left side of the page. How do I fix this?

http://www.student.nvcc.edu/home/kosindi/test/ul.html

That is a link to my website which has an example of my problem.

Please explain your logic, thank you.

Comment: try using margin: 0 auto; to center instead of text-align: center;

Comment: if there is no any other content you can do it with `padding-left:45%`

Answer (score -1):

You have two variants, choose one:

1.Use this CSS and it will work:

```
li { list-style-position: inside; }
```

2.If you want the basket balls to appear one under another then use this CSS:

```
body { text-align: left; }
ul { width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: You just modify my answer

Answer (score -1):

as per your HTML code you gave in link just few change will do.

in css

```
body {
    padding-left: 45%; // add this css
    text-align: left; // change this css
}
```

Comment: If you check his html link he has only css there.
and that is why i say as per his given HTML code